# Sending emails with inline images in Google App Engine (Java)

Tags: java, email, google-app-engine, inline-images

I am trying to send email with inline images in Google App Engine (Java).
Here is my code.

```
public void send(RecepientInfo[] toAddress, String subject, Attachment[] attachements) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    try {
        MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();

        msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(utils.getSenderInfo());
        for (RecepientInfo address : toAddress) {
            msg.addRecipient(address.getType(), address.getAddress());
        }
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        Template textTpl = cfg.getTemplate("text.ftl");
        Template htmlTpl = cfg.getTemplate("html.ftl");
        StringWriter swText = new StringWriter();
        StringWriter swHtml = new StringWriter();
        textTpl.process(parameters, swText);
        htmlTpl.process(parameters, swHtml);
        String html = swHtml.toString();
        String text = swText.toString();
        textPart.setText(text, "text/plain");
        htmlPart.setContent(html, "text/html");
        mp.addBodyPart(textPart);
        mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

        if (attachements != null) {
            for (Attachment item : attachements) {
                mp.addBodyPart(getImageMultiPart(item.base64Content.getBytes(), item.mimeType, item.contentId, item.fileName, MimeBodyPart.INLINE));
            }
        }

        msg.setContent(mp);
        Transport.send(msg);
        if (Constants.IS_DEV_MODE) {
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    } catch (TemplateException te) {
        throw new IOException(te);
    }
}

private BodyPart getImageMultiPart(byte[] base64EncodedImageContentByteArray, String mimeType, String contentId, String fileName, String bodyPart) throws MessagingException {
    InternetHeaders headers = new InternetHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("Content-Type", mimeType);
    headers.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
    MimeBodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart(headers, base64EncodedImageContentByteArray);
    imagePart.setDisposition(bodyPart);
    if (contentId != null) {
        imagePart.setContentID("&lt;" + contentId + "&gt;");
    }
    if (fileName != null) {
        imagePart.setFileName(fileName);
    }
    return imagePart;
}
```

But when I am trying to send the mail, I am getting some errors like this:

```
com.google.api.server.spi.response.InternalServerErrorException: Send failure (javax.mail.MessagingException: Illegal Arguments (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Attachment Type: Invalid attachment type))
    at com.fms.advocacy.api.content.ContentApi.email(ContentApi.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:130)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:363)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:113)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.fms.advocacy.filters.AccessRuleFilter.doFilter(AccessRuleFilter.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.fms.advocacy.filters.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:37)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.fms.advocacy.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:27)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.fms.advocacy.filters.ErrorHandlerFilter.doFilter(ErrorHandlerFilter.java:36)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:512)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Send failure (javax.mail.MessagingException: Illegal Arguments (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Attachment Type: Invalid attachment type))
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:163)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)
    at com.fms.advocacy.AdvocacyMail.send(AdvocacyMail.java:100)
    at com.fms.advocacy.api.content.ContentApi.email(ContentApi.java:184)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Illegal Arguments (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Attachment Type: Invalid attachment type)
    at com.google.appengine.api.mail.stdimpl.GMTransport.sendMessage(GMTransport.java:231)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:95)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Attachment Type: Invalid attachment type
    at com.google.appengine.api.mail.MailServiceImpl.doSend(MailServiceImpl.java:113)
    at com.google.appengine.api.mail.MailServiceImpl.send(MailServiceImpl.java:34)
    at com.google.appengine.api.mail.stdimpl.GMTransport.sendMessage(GMTransport.java:223)
    ... 57 more
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was silly.

When I set `setFileName`, I had to pass a string with proper extension.

so instead of

```
imagePart.setFileName(fileName);
```

I have to use

```
imagePart.setFileName(fileName + "." + mimeType.substring(mimeType.indexOf("/") + 1));
```